# cannot convert the expressions type UIImage to type void swift

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

Im having an issue, I am trying to create a method which accepts a PFObject as a parameter. The PFObject in this case is the facebook picture URL. The method takes the URL and basically converts it into an image. I can get it to work if i just use this block of code without trying to make it into a method, however I would like to create a method out of this so that I dont have to keep repeating myself. When i try to return the users image i keep getting the error `cannot convert the expressions type UIImage to type void swift`

Here is the code

```
func downloadFBUserImage(object: PFObject?) -> UIImage? {
var userProfilePhotoURLString = object?.valueForKey("pictureURL") as String?
if userProfilePhotoURLString != nil {
    var pictureURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: userProfilePhotoURLString!)!
    var urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: pictureURL)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (NSURLResponse response, NSData data, NSError error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            var userProfilePic: UIImage? = UIImage(data: data)
            return userProfilePic
        }


    })
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is reporting that the `completionHandler` of the `sendAsynchronousRequest` is defined to pass you the `response`, `data`, and `error` objects, but that it expects that `completionHandler`, itself, to not return any values. But you're trying to return a value from within that `completionHandler` closure.

Bottom line, you cannot simply return the `UIImage` from your function, because you are performing asynchronous method (i.e. the data is returned later even though you return from the function immediately). So, employ asynchronous pattern:

```
func downloadFBUserImage(object: PFObject?, completionHandler: (UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    if let userProfilePhotoURLString = object?.valueForKey("pictureURL") as? String {
        let pictureURL = NSURL(string: userProfilePhotoURLString)!
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: pictureURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in
            if data != nil {
                var userProfilePic = UIImage(data: data)
                completionHandler(userProfilePic, nil)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd call it using the same completion handler pattern that `sendAsynchronousRequest` does:

```
downloadFBUserImage(object) { image, error in 
    if image == nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        // use the image here
    }
}

// but don't try to use asynchronously retrieved image here
```

Comment: ahh okay! I always assumed that since the completion handler is located within a function, it could also return a value. Thank you for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return to the completion block like that. The completion block does not have a return parameter. This is why you are getting an error.

For updating the image after download, you can pass in a block along with your `downloadFBUserImage` function like below.

I used `dispatch_async` because UI updates have to be done on the main thread.

```
func downloadFBUserImage(object: PFObject?, completion completionBlock:(UIImage) -> ()) -> (){
    var userProfilePhotoURLString = object?.valueForKey("pictureURL") as String?
    if userProfilePhotoURLString != nil {
        var pictureURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: userProfilePhotoURLString!)!
        var urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: pictureURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (NSURLResponse response, NSData data, NSError error) -> Void in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                if let userProfilePic = UIImage(data: data) {
                   completionBlock(userProfilePic)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It can be called like this

```
func do() {
    downloadFBUserImage(pfObject, completion: { (image) -> () in
            //updateImage
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
              // UI updates
          }
    })
}
```